# using PowerShell, Is there an easier or better optimized way to get the download link to the latest Nvidia Driver?

Tags: powershell, refactoring

Hello all, I've been able to get this code to get the latest download link for Nvidia Driver for a Quadro P1000.
I was wondering, if there's a better way to do this.

Here's my code:

```ps
#Get Nvidia Drivers
            #This next section is JUST TO get the LINK to the LATEST driver from Nvidia
            #WebContent gets the links that are "href" from the nvidia JS request. No idea if there's an easier wey to get this.
            $Webcontent = (Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.nvidia.com/Download/processFind.aspx?psid=73&pfid=842&osid=57&lid=1&whql=&lang=en-us&ctk=0&qnfslb=10&dtcid=0').links.href 
            #The following line uses Regex regular expressions to MATCH and RETRIEVE ONE single value from the list of values in the previous line.
            $NVIDIALinkToLatestDriver = [regex]::Match($Webcontent, '//(www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/[0-9]*/en-us)').Groups[1].Value
            #Link after the previous crap
            $NVIDIADLPage = New-Object -COM "HTMLFile" #Creates a COM Object for easier search of the link.
            [string]$htmlBody = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $NVIDIALinkToLatestDriver -UseBasicParsing).Content #Parses the content of the landing page to then look by id
            $NVIDIADLPage.write([ref]$htmlBody)
            $replace = [regex]::Replace($NVIDIADLPage.getElementById('lnkDwnldBtn').href, 'about:', 'www.nvidia.com') #Replaces the "about" with "www.nvidia.com"
            $Webcontent = (Invoke-WebRequest $replace) #Replace Webcontent with the latest link.
            [String]$NvidiaLinkToExe = $Webcontent.links.href -match ".*.exe$" #On this link there's the exe file for Nvidia Drivers
            $NvidiaLinkToExe = $NvidiaLinkToExe -replace "^", "http:" #Replace start of line with the correct Nvidia Link.
            Remove-Variable -Name NVIDIADLPage, Webcontent, replace -Force #cleanup of the previous mess.
            if ($NvidiaLinkToExe -match 'http:\/\/.*[0-9]{2}\/(([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}).*\.exe)') {
                $NVIDIAExeToDownload = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Url     = $Matches[0];
                    Name    = $Matches[1];
                    Version = $Matches[2]
                }
            }
```

As you can see, I have to create three `Invoke-WebRequest` just to get one link.
And, I think I made no use of piping, because I was unable to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems better than mine. I had to call Invoke-WebRequest 3 times to get the link as well and once more to download it.

```
$destination = 'C:\Temp'
$downloadlist = 'https://www.nvidia.com/Download/processFind.aspx?psid=73&pfid=842&osid=57&lid=1&whql=&lang=en-us&ctk=0&qnfslb=10&dtcid=0'

$pattern = "(?s)<tr>.+?href='//(?<URL>.+?)'>.+?<td.+?>(?<Version>.+?)</td.+?td.+?>(?<Date>.+?)</td.+</tr>"
$content = Invoke-WebRequest $downloadlist -UseBasicParsing

$download = if($content.RawContent -match $pattern){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        URL     = $Matches.URL
        Version = $Matches.Version
        Date    = $Matches.Date
    }
}

$pattern = '(?s)(?<Package>/content/driver[^"]+?{0}/.+?)(?=")' -f ($download.Version -replace '.+\(|\)')
$content = Invoke-WebRequest $download.url -UseBasicParsing

if($content.RawContent -match $pattern){
    $pattern = '//(?<Package>.+?{0}.+exe)' -f ($download.Version -replace '.+\(|\)')
    $content = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.nvidia.com$($Matches.Package)" -UseBasicParsing

    if($content.RawContent -match $pattern){
        Invoke-WebRequest "https://$($Matches.Package)" -OutFile (Join-Path $destination $($Matches.package -replace '.+/'))
    }
}
```

If you just want the link and other info you can drop the fourth.

```
$downloadlist = 'https://www.nvidia.com/Download/processFind.aspx?psid=73&pfid=842&osid=57&lid=1&whql=&lang=en-us&ctk=0&qnfslb=10&dtcid=0'

$content = Invoke-WebRequest $downloadlist -UseBasicParsing

$download = if($content.RawContent -match "(?s)<tr>.+?href='//(?<URL>.+?)'>.+?<td.+?>(?<Version>.+?)</td.+?td.+?>(?<Date>.+?)</td.+</tr>"){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        URL     = $Matches.URL
        Version = $Matches.Version
        Date    = $Matches.Date
    }
}

$pattern = '(?s)(?<Package>/content/driver[^"]+?{0}/.+?)(?=")' -f ($download.Version -replace '.+\(|\)')
$content = Invoke-WebRequest $download.url -UseBasicParsing

if($content.RawContent -match $pattern){
    $pattern = '//(?<Package>.+?{0}.+exe)' -f ($download.Version -replace '.+\(|\)')
    $content = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.nvidia.com$($Matches.Package)" -UseBasicParsing

    $download.URL = "https://$($Matches.Package)"
    $download
}
```

Comment: All right, thanks for the alternate version, the idea was to cut down on the invoke-webrequest as it was the one that took the most time, but it's a good alternative.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it’s the dynamic nature of their site that requires multiple calls.